# Distance an object covers before stopping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction

> Mass of an object is $2kg$ and its speed is $10 \frac{m}{s}$ the moment it passes point $A$ and it stops on point $B$. The linear road from $A$ to $B$ has $\frac{1}{2}$ coefficient of friction ($\mu$).
>
> Find the length of $AB$ road.

I took it this far: Force of friction is

$$F_{friction} = \mu \times m \times g = \frac {1}{2} \times 2kg \times 10$$

$$F_{friction}= 10 N$$

then applying Newton's Second Law

$$F= m \times a$$

$$10N = 2kg \times a$$

$$a=5$$

Object should lose $5\frac{m}{s}$ of speed each second and therefore stop after two seconds after passing point $A$.

Speed function of the object therefore is $y=-5x+10$ and its integral should give us the total distance taken which equals the length of $AB$

$$\int_{0}^{2} (-5x+10)dx=10$$

However, the answer is 30 according to my book. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Update: I contacted the publisher and made sure that answer was indeed **10**.

Comment: I got the same answer.  It may just be an error in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Since the initial kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = 100J$ and we know the friction force is equal to $10N$ then we also know that $ 100 = 10 \cdot S$ because $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = F \cdot S $.

Your answer of $10$ seems to agree with both approaches so your answer to the question as stated appears to be correct.